# How to set text view if something happened in another class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

I have a text view in my ActivityMain and I have an adapter(for my recycler view) that if the user touches something value of text view should be changed.

Text view is in another part of the screen and is not related to recycler view.

how can I do that?

thank you.

Comment: post your code...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: You can use Broadcast Receiver or interface for your purpose. Try to find out examples of both of these, you'll find plenty of it. Happy coding

Comment: Try to create interface in your adapter. Also you can pass string value in the parameters. Now you can access this interface in any class.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to create a callback function. You need to define an interface as a contractor between your activity and the other class that you need to inform the activity.

Implement the interface inside your activity and pass its reference to the other class and call that reference whenever you need.

Answer (score 1):

put a Receiver inside your ActivityMain Class like

```
BroadcastReceiver receiverFragmentImages = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("extra"));
        }
    };
```

and register it like...

```
registerReceiver(receiverFragmentImages , new IntentFilter("trigger"));
```

and call it like

```
Intent intent = new Intent("trigger");
intent.putStringExtra("extra", "data");
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score -2):

simple  solution is to declare your text view as public static and access in adapter class using activity name and assign text on click

Comment: down vote: memory leak since you are using a static variable inside an instance that could be vanished from memory at any time, besides its not a good design (your code smells very bad!!!)